# How to programmatically merge calls in Android?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, telecom-manager

**In Call Service**

Am using [InCallService](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telecom/InCallService) to listen for incoming call and in [onCallStateChanged](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/PhoneStateListener#onCallStateChanged(int,%20java.lang.String)) callback am updating call state, I have successfully achieved till holding 'call 1' and connecting 'call 2', so 'call 1' is on **HOLD** and 'call 2' is on **ACTIVE** state respectively, now when I tap on merge, it throws an error as

> **"Unable to merge calls"**

Am using [Conference method](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telecom/Call#conference(android.telecom.Call)) to merge calls

For better understanding, am posting my code below

```
 class CallService : InCallService() {

    override fun onCallAdded(call: Call) {
        super.onCallAdded(call)
        CallManager.updateCall(call)

    }

    private val callCallback = object : Call.Callback() {
        override fun onStateChanged(call: Call, state: Int) {
            CallManager.updateCall(call)
        }
    }

    override fun onCallRemoved(call: Call) {
        super.onCallRemoved(call)
        call.unregisterCallback(callCallback)
        CallManager.updateCall(null)
    }
}


@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
object CallManager {
    private const val LOG_TAG = "CallManager"
    private val subject = BehaviorSubject.create<GsmCall>()
    private var currentCall: Call? = null
    private var anotherCall: Call? = null
    fun updates(): Observable<GsmCall> = subject


    fun updateCall(call: Call?) {
        if (currentCall != null) {
            call?.let {
                if (it.details.handle.schemeSpecificPart ==
                    currentCall!!.details.handle.schemeSpecificPart
                )
                    currentCall = call
                else anotherCall = call
            }
        } else currentCall = call
        call?.let {
            subject.onNext(it.toGsmCall())
        }
    }


    fun cancelCall() {
        currentCall?.let {
            when (it.state) {
                Call.STATE_RINGING -> rejectCall()
                else -> disconnectCall()
            }
        }
    }


    fun holdCall() {
        currentCall?.let {
            when (it.state) {
                Call.STATE_ACTIVE -> currentCall?.hold()
                else -> Log.i(LOG_TAG, "Call not in connected state")
            }
        }
    }

//Conference call method
    fun conferenceCall() {
        anotherCall?.conference(currentCall)
    }

    fun swapConferenceCall() {
        currentCall?.swapConference()
    }

    fun mergeConferenceCall() {
        currentCall?.mergeConference()
    }

    fun unHoldCall() {
        currentCall?.let {
            when (it.state) {
                Call.STATE_HOLDING -> currentCall?.unhold()
                else -> Log.i(LOG_TAG, "Call not in connected state")
            }
        }
    }

    fun isCallOnHold(): Boolean {
        currentCall?.let {

            return when (it.state) {
                Call.STATE_HOLDING -> true
                else -> false
            }
        }
        return false
    }

    fun acceptCall() {
        Log.i(LOG_TAG, "acceptCall")
        currentCall?.let {
            it.answer(it.details.videoState)
        }
    }

    private fun rejectCall() {
        Log.i(LOG_TAG, "rejectCall")
        currentCall?.reject(false, "")
    }

    private fun disconnectCall() {
        Log.i(LOG_TAG, "disconnectCall")
        currentCall?.disconnect()
    }

}
```

Comment: Hi, did you solve this?

Answer (score 0):

```
 anotherCall?.conference(currentCall)
 currentCall?.mergeConference();//add this line
```